# Delay function in SpriteKit (Swift 3) not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

After looking at several other questions like this, all the answers from their questions are not working for me. I have a pause label, and when the user presses play, I want the label to go from "Paused" to countdown from 3 to 1. I've declared the

```
let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
```

as my delay, and that's what others seem to be doing, but it's not working for me.

```
func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
        pauseLabel.text = "3"
        pauseLabel.run(delay)
        pauseLabel.text = "2"
        pauseLabel.run(delay)
        pauseLabel.text = "1"
        pauseLabel.run(delay)
        pauseLabel.removeFromParent()
        pauseLabel.run(delay)
        addChild(scoreLabel)
        addChild(levelLabel)
        addChild(hero)
        addEnemies()
        play.removeFromSuperview()
        createPauseButton()

    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your actions are running at once.

What you need to do is...(by the way "-> void" is not necessary)

the {} brackets after the SKAction are shorthand for `completion:` so it designates code to run once the action has completed. Your code just runs all of the actions at once, the delays are running as well but nothing is firing after they are run.

```
func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) {

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

    pauseLabel.text = "3"
    pauseLabel.run(delay) {

        pauseLabel.text = "2"
        pauseLabel.run(delay) {

            pauseLabel.text = "1"
            pauseLabel.run(delay) {

                pauseLabel.removeFromParent()
                pauseLabel.run(delay) {

                    addChild(scoreLabel)
                    addChild(levelLabel)
                    addChild(hero)
                    addEnemies()
                    play.removeFromSuperview()
                    createPauseButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. This approach guarantee the correct completion of your actions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call run on a node, action takes place immediately, so all your actions are run almost at once. You need to create a sequence of actions like:

```
// elementary actions
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
let text3 = SKAction.run({ pauseLabel="3" })
let text2 = SKAction.run({ pauseLabel="3" })
let text1 = SKAction.run({ pauseLabel="3" })
let end = SKAction.run({
    addChild(scoreLabel)
    addChild(levelLabel)
    addChild(hero)
    addEnemies()
    play.removeFromSuperview()
    createPauseButton()
})
// sequenced action
let seq = SKAction.sequence([ text3, delay, text2, delay, text1, delay, remove,end]}

pauseLabel.run(seq) // now launch the sequence...
```